# passing values to a flag in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes

I am preparing shell(.sh) scripts to use my kubernetes and pks command line 
in kubernetes command we have flags like --image and i am not able to pass the arguments in it

i have tried the convential way of passing the arguments like 
image=$1

echo $image

the echo statement prints the value well and good $ name is also passing in the command but the script give the error image  needed i.e image is not given in the command.

```
image=$1
hostPort=$2
name=$3
echo $image
kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify run $name --image= $image --port= $hostPort
```

the echo statement prints the value well and good $ name is also passing in the command but the script give the error image  needed i.e image is not given in the command.

Comment: Also I am new to the community so please feel free to edit my question if it needed any correction :-)

Comment: Try removing the space after `=`. Also, double quote the variables so special characters in paths are preserved.

Comment: @deepankursingh If the answer has helped you, consider upvoting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options such as `--image` must typically be separated by *either* space or an equals sign from their value. So `--image="$image"` and `--image "$image"` will probably both work. "Typically" and "probably" because there's nothing stopping someone from writing some really crazy argument handling to actually support the way it's run here, but I've never seen that before.

Comment: thanks for the help `--image=$image` worked `--image="$image"` will send $image as a string in the argument